# Unable to run a function in an object and print a new array - a bit confused

Tags: javascript

```js
const ancientWonders = {
  // name of the list
  name: "The Ancient Wonders of the World",
  // list of locations
  list: [
    [29.97916667, 31.13416667, "Great Pyramid of Giza"],
    [33.5355, 44.2475, "Hanging Gardens of Babylon"],
    [37.63777778, 21.63, "Statue of Zeus at Olympia"],
    [37.94972222, 27.36388889, "Temple of Artemis at Ephesus"],
    [37.03777778, 27.42416667, "Mausoleum at Halicarnassus"],
    [36.4511, 28.2278, "Colossus Rhodes"],
    [31.21388889, 29.88555556, "Lighthouse of Alexandria"],
  ],
  // to store all distances between points
  distances: [],
  // to store shortest trip in list
  shortest: [],
  // to store longest trip in list
  longest: [],
  // function to convert above coordinatates into radians
  calcRad: function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < this.list[i].length; c++) {
        if (typeof this.list[i][c] !== "number") continue;
        const rad = (this.list[i][c] * Math.PI) / 180;
        return rad;
      }
    }
    this.distances.push(rad);
  },
  // to store direct route between points
  directRoute: [],
};

console.log(ancientWonders.calcRad(ancientWonders.distances));
```

For some reason, it only calculates the first coordinate of array 1 in the console..

could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Post your code here as text please.

Comment: done. please see above :)

Comment: You have `return rad;` inside the loop, so the function returns after calculating the first coordinate. How do you expect it to return multiple values?

Comment: You probably want to create a new array and push to it where you're returning, instead of returning inside the for loop, which will exit your function immediately and not iterate over the other items

Comment: A short explanation what you intend to do with your code would make it easier for others to propose a solution to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly no need to pass an arugment to `calcRad`. You are not using any in your method.

You are returning from inside the loop and that is why it is not run for all the items. Infact, your `distances` array is still empty and you just returned the first value. You need to move the return statement outside the loop, so **after** all the items are done, then you can return a suitable value.

Also, you need to run the loop for all the items while pushing. So have to move the push statement inside the first for loop.

```js
const ancientWonders = {
  // name of the list
  name: "The Ancient Wonders of the World",
  // list of locations
  list: [
    [29.97916667, 31.13416667, "Great Pyramid of Giza"],
    [33.5355, 44.2475, "Hanging Gardens of Babylon"],
    [37.63777778, 21.63, "Statue of Zeus at Olympia"],
    [37.94972222, 27.36388889, "Temple of Artemis at Ephesus"],
    [37.03777778, 27.42416667, "Mausoleum at Halicarnassus"],
    [36.4511, 28.2278, "Colossus Rhodes"],
    [31.21388889, 29.88555556, "Lighthouse of Alexandria"],
  ],
  // to store all distances between points
  distances: [],
  // to store shortest trip in list
  shortest: [],
  // to store longest trip in list
  longest: [],
  // function to convert above coordinatates into radians
  calcRad: function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) { 
      let rad = null;
      for (let c = 0; c < this.list[i].length; c++) {
        if (typeof this.list[i][c] !== "number") continue;
        rad = (this.list[i][c] * Math.PI) / 180;
      }
      this.distances.push(rad);
    }
    return this.distances;
  },
  // to store direct route between points
  directRoute: [],
};

console.log(ancientWonders.calcRad());
```

Comment: thanks so much - this is super clear to me now! In the case I wanted to create an object `distances` instead of an array to store each radian value pair alongside the Ancient Wonder name value, how would I go around that?

Comment: Glad. Firstly, you would define like this `distances: {}` cause object. And then instead of push, set a property after every outer loop iteration , try this : `this.distances[this.list[i][2]] = rad;` Not editing the solution because that is not a part of the question

Answer (score 0):

There are two numeric values that the code appears to care about in the inner array (values that the inner loop traverses, checking for numbers).

The OP code is assigning the calculation for each of those two values to the same variable.  Here, not sure what output is expected, I've added the result of each calculation to an object that gets pushed onto the `distances` array.

```js
const ancientWonders = {
  // name of the list
  name: "The Ancient Wonders of the World",
  // list of locations
  list: [
    [29.97916667, 31.13416667, "Great Pyramid of Giza"],
    [33.5355, 44.2475, "Hanging Gardens of Babylon"],
    [37.63777778, 21.63, "Statue of Zeus at Olympia"],
    [37.94972222, 27.36388889, "Temple of Artemis at Ephesus"],
    [37.03777778, 27.42416667, "Mausoleum at Halicarnassus"],
    [36.4511, 28.2278, "Colossus Rhodes"],
    [31.21388889, 29.88555556, "Lighthouse of Alexandria"],
  ],
  // to store all distances between points
  distances: [],
  // to store shortest trip in list
  shortest: [],
  // to store longest trip in list
  longest: [],
  // function to convert above coordinatates into radians
  calcRad: function () {
    const deg2Rad = deg => deg * Math.PI / 180.0;
    this.distances = this.list.map(item => {
      return {
        name: item[2],
        angleAInDegrees: item[0],
        angleBInDegrees: item[1],
        angleAInRadians: deg2Rad(item[0]),
        angleBInRadians: deg2Rad(item[1]),
      }
    });
  },
  // to store direct route between points
  directRoute: [],
};

ancientWonders.calcRad()
console.log(ancientWonders.distances);
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks so much! In the case I wanted to create an object `distances` instead of an array to store each radian value pair alongside the Ancient Wonder name value, how would I go around that?

Comment: Happy to help.  I think I understand the follow up to want an array of objects rather than an array of arrays.  Please see edit to lmk if that's what you mean.  The trick is selecting appropriate keys.